# Can I merge multiple cells into one cell in Google Sheets with formula? (Example sheet provided)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet with multiple items in individual cells (For example: all simpson family members 'Homer, Marge, Bart' etc all in C3, all spice girls in C5 etc).

I want to split them up so they're one under the other in a list.

Is their a way to do this for the entire column?

My examples is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z3pnPCDEWewsHCpehrYMQ3QbZD8-GsfG_LFNFdQkP-M/edit?usp=sharing) including what I want it to look like, and a test formula (=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(C3, ","))

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","&CHAR(10),,C3:C),","&CHAR(10)))
```

---

FYI, It's a little more complicated in Excel, but if you got ExcelO365 then try:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(","&CHAR(10),,C3:C5),","&CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")
```

Otherwise it's still possible but you'd want to use `INDEX` to pull values out of the array.